# How to set timestamp as an index for a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe called 'trial'. I have combined the Date and Time in the data frame to get a field which has timestamp as a POSIXct. I want to set this combined date time or the timestampas the index for my data frame 'trial' how can I do so? I have seen similar questions on this with no success.
The code is as follows:

```
 trial <- read.csv("2018_05_04_h093500.csv", header=TRUE, skip = 16, sep=",")
 trial$Date <- with(trial, as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(Date, format="%Y/%m/%d"), Time)))
 dtPOSIXct <- as.POSIXct(trial$Date )
 dtTime <- as.numeric(dtPOSIXct - trunc(dtPOSIXct, "days"))
 class(dtTime) <- "POSIXct"
```

Comment: May be `format(Sys.time(), "%a_%b_%d_%Y")`? Your question is not clear though.

Comment: I want the timestamp as the index of the dataframe like how in python it is: trial.index=pd.to_datetime(trial.Date+" "+trial.Time

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about rownames which is the R equivalent to index in pandas, they can't be POSIXct datetimes, they have to be characters.

```
# sample data
x <- data.frame('a' = 1:3, 'b' = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
print(x)

#                    a b
#2018-01-01 15:51:33 1 a
#2018-01-04 11:42:31 2 b
#2018-01-07 22:04:41 3 c

dates <- c('2018-01-01 15:51:33', '2018-01-04 11:42:31', '2018-01-07 22:04:41')
rownames(x) <- as.POSIXct(dates, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(class(rownames(x)[1]))
# [1] "character"
```

That said, you can still coerce them to POSIXct (or any other class, obviously) at the time of evaluation at the cost of some overhead and code clutteredness:

```
# print x where rownames, when coerced to POSIXct, represent dates after d
d <- as.POSIXct('2018-01-03 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
x[as.POSIXct(rownames(x), format = f) > d, ]

#                    a b
#2018-01-04 11:42:31 2 b
#2018-01-07 22:04:41 3 c
```

However, perhaps an easier approach would be to just have an arbitrary column effectively act as a datetime index:

```
x$date <- as.POSIXct(dates, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
class(x$date[1])
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. The problem is how to make the timestamp as the index?? and arbitrary column index wont help. How can I make this timestamp as an index. I have many files like this.

Comment: Quick answer is, you can't. If you're okay with coercing them to characters, then `rownames(x) <- timestamps`

Comment: OK. rownames(x)<-timestamps does not work. If I keep the timestamp as characters. how can I make it an index? set_index??

Comment: It was just a general case, in your specific example it's `rownames(trial) <- trial$Date`. Again, the equivalent of [pandas] index in R dataframes is rownames. There is no such method as `set_index()`, unfortunately.

Comment: I have converted the trial$Date into character like this: trial$Date<-as.character(trial$Date) and then executed  rownames(trial) <- trial$Date. But the indexing remains the same as original.

Comment: You don't need to coerce trial$Date to character explicitly, `rownames()` takes care of that automatically. What do you mean by indexing? Perhaps you mean the rows are in the wrong order?

Comment: By indexing I mean that that the other values like BC in trial come with 1 , 2, 3, 4, as their indexes when trial$BC is executed where BC is another column in trial. I need timestamp to be indexed with BC not the integers.